# Why does capistrano return different fetch than set vars

Tags: capistrano3

having a problem with capistrano 3.

Whenever I set a value that is not a string, when fetching, the value is gone, I am expecting an empty Hash:

```
namespace :something

  set :my_var, Hash.new

  task :do_something do
    fetch(:my_var) # this is empty, no way to get a hash here, always a string
  end
end
```

There is probably a way to achieve this but this is very counterintuitive and does not work as I hoped.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this myself and it seems to do what you expect: https://github.com/will-in-wi/cap_3_variable_test

If I create a folder, install Capistrano, and then create this as my `deploy.rb`:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :my_var, Hash.new

namespace :something do
  task :do_something do
    puts fetch(:my_var).class
    puts fetch(:my_var)
  end
end
```

And run `bundle exec cap staging something:do_something`, I get:

```
Hash
{}
```

Could you look at this example and let me know if you see any major differences?

Comment: And when you set the hash inside a block supposed to be executed within a remote host?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking what happens if the hash is set within a block, e.g. within task :do_something?

Comment: Yes, specifically a block that is supposed to be run on a remote server. We have observed that the symbol simply isn't set at all and remains nil.